# Store dropdown in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to store options for a select box in a database? I need to store all options in one single column field. Users will be allow to create there own custom dropdown options for a custom field and I am unsure on how to save all the options to build it dynamically from mysql with php. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the select options in the database as JSON. To do this you would use `json_encode` on the options array, then store the value in your database.

```
// an array of options
$opts = array('An option', 'Another option', 'A third option');
// json encode the array for storage in the database
$dbValue = json_encode($opts);
// your code to save in the database goes here
```

To retrieve the options you would use `json_decode` to convert it back to an array of options.

```
// your code to retrieve the value from the database goes here
// json decode the array stored in the database
$out = json_decode($dbValue);
// output the select
echo '<select>';
// loop through the options and output
foreach ($out as $opt)
{
    echo '<option>'.$opt.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```